# How to improve LESS code to get a compact CSS result?

Tags: less

**My attempt:**

```
 .breadcrumb {
  &.main,
  &.path {
     & a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

.left-sidepanel {
    .panel {
      &-heading,
      &-body a {
        color: red;
      }
    }
  }
```

**Result:**

```
.breadcrumb.main a:hover,
.breadcrumb.path a:hover {
  color: red;
}

.left-sidepanel .panel-heading,
.left-sidepanel .panel-body a {
  color: red;
}
```

**The required result**

```
.breadcrumb.main a:hover,
.breadcrumb.path a:hover,    
.left-sidepanel .panel-heading,
.left-sidepanel .panel-body a {
  color: red;
}
```

I would be grateful for your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.breadcrumb {
  &.main,
  &.path {
     a:hover {
      color: red;
    }
  }
}

.left-sidepanel {
    .panel {
      &-heading,
      &-body a {
        &:extend(.breadcrumb.path a:hover);
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Fine, except one should avoid redundant nesting ("overnesting" is a common mistake of those who start learning Less). E.g. `.left-sidepanel { .panel {...}}` should really be just `.left-sidepanel .panel {...}` etc. and so on. Just notice how your result CSS is gorgeously more readable than all those brackets.